# 3sat to clique reduction program

Tags: p-vs-np, 3-sat, clique, java

I am searching for a program to convert 3sat to clique problem.

I tried following links

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximal-clique-problem-recursive-solution/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-all-cliques-of-size-k-in-an-undirected-graph/

But it is not converting 3sat problem.

Is there any algorithm to convert 3sat to clique ?

Comment: If you're looking for a (polynomial-time) algorithm to convert an instance of 3-SAT to an instance of the decision version of CLIQUE (given a graph, decide whether there is a clique with $k$ vertices), then there is an easy polynomial-time reduction which I can sketch in an answer. If you're looking for an already-made implementation then I'm not aware of one (although it is straightforward to write from the reduction).

Comment: I know implementation but I want a code which do the reduction. please can you provide me code?

Answer (score 1):

Let 3-SAT formula $\phi$ be $C_1 \wedge C_2 \wedge \dots \wedge C_m$, where $C_i$ is a clause consisting of the disjunction of three literals: $(\ell_i^1 \vee \ell_i^2 \vee \ell_i^3)$.

We can create an auxiliary graph $G$ as follows:

- For each clause $C_i$ create three vertices $\ell_i^1, \ell_i^2, \ell_i^3$, i.e., one for each literal. And add all edges between them.
- Add an edge between each pair of complementary literals. I.e., if $\ell_i^h$ and $\ell_j^k$ refer to the same variable but one literal is positive and the other is negated, then add the edge $(\ell_i^h, \ell_j^k)$.

Let $\overline{G}$ be the complement of $G$ (i.e., $\overline{G}$ has the same vertex set as $G$ and it contains an edge $e$ if and only if $e$ is not in $G$).

**Claim: The 3-SAT formula $\phi$ is satisfiable if and only if $\overline{G}$ contains a clique of size $m$.**

Proof ($\Longrightarrow$):  Consider a truth assignment that satisfies $\phi$ and, for each clause $C_i$ choose a literal $\ell^*_i$ that is true according to such an assignment.
Notice that the set $L = \{\ell^*_i \mid i=1,\dots,m\}$ contains exactly one literal per clause (by definition) and does not contain any pair of complementary literals (since they cannot both be true). Then $L$ is an independent set of size $m$ of $G$, which means that the subgraph induced by $L$ must be a clique of size $m$ in to complement $\overline{G}$ of $G$.

Proof ($\Longleftarrow$): Let $L$ be the vertices of a of size $m$ in $\overline{G}$ and notice that $L$ must be an independent set in $G$.
Since no independent set of $G$ can contain two literals from the same clause (all literals from the same clause have an edge between them), and since there are exactly $m$ clauses, $L$ contains exactly one literal $\ell_i^*$ from each clause $C_i$.
Moreover, this set of literals cannot contain any pair of complementary literals. Then you can find a satisfying assignment for $\phi$ by setting the variables according to the values of the literals in $L$. The "leftover" variables (if any) that do not correspond to any literal in $L$ can be set arbitrarily.

Here is the pseudocode of a possible implementation:

```
Inputs: 
- the number m of triplets
- a list L of m triples. The generic j-th element of the i-th triple, denoted by L[i][j], contains either the index k>=1 of a variable to encode the positive literal on the k-th variable, or -k to encode the negated literal

Output: the list of edges of the graph resulting from the above reduction. The vertices of the graph are integers from 1 to 3m. The j-th literal of the i-th clause is vertex (i-1)*3+j.

For i = 1,2,...,m-1:
   For i' = i+1, i+2,....,m:
      For j = 1,2,3:
         For j' = 1,2,3:
            If L[i][j] != -L[i'][j']:
                Output the edge ((i-1)*3 + j, (i'-1)*3 + j')
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but is there any online code for the reduction ?

Comment: As I said I'm not aware of any readily made implementation. However it should be quite simple to implement the above reduction. You just need to add edges of a graph expect those between two literals that are complementary or belong to the same clause.

Comment: I've added the pseudocode of a possible implementation.